# Click Google+1 Button using vb.net

Tags: google-plus

Google+1 has such a complex code that it changes on mouse over as the option appears to select the circle in which we need to have.

Can you tell me how can i add a google plus one page to circle using vb.net?

Answer (score 1):

The [Google+ Badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/) is the only way to add a page to a circle without visiting plus.google.com and it requires direct action from a user.